# Probability of rolling a sum of at least 18 with 10 6-sided dice

Tags: probability, dice

I'm trying to work out how to do this, and I'm very stuck. My grasp of probability is shaky to begin with, and generally with probability questions, I list out cases. Due to the number of possibilities, this one is beyond my grasp. I can't even think of a quick way to figure out which combinations would lead to a sum of 18, without listing all possible cases, so [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644989/the-probability-of-the-sum-of-10-dice-rolls-adding-up-to-57) isn't so helpful right no.

I searched here first, but unfortunately, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36677/whats-the-probability-of-rolling-at-least-k-on-n-dice-with-s-1-ldots-s-n) is beyond me, and the link in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366949/computing-the-probability-of-rolling-a-sum-of-18-on-4-six-sided-dice) isn't working.

Comment: It still requires a fair amount of listing, but one approach is to compute the *complementary* probability of getting a sum that's *less than* $18$.  Note that the sum is always at least $10$.

Comment: Thanks @BarryCipra I will try this now.

Comment: A simple Python script yields $19338$ combinations that sum up to less than $18$, hence the probability is $1-\frac{19338}{6^{10}}\approx99.968\%$

Comment: Funny, I'd have thought the normal distribution would give a better result than it does, but I guess $18$ is just too much of an outlier.

Comment: @BrianTung: My calculation with the normal curve approximation comes out at $99.94\%$, which seems pretty close to me (granted that it's not even at the canonical large sample size of 30+).

Comment: Hmm.  I got $99.92\%$, but I didn't do it terribly carefully.  But even with your (closer) result, that's still about a factor of two.  I guess that's not terribly surprising, but nonetheless I expected a bit better than that.

Comment: Check [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/993044#993044), it is not too hard to understand, you only need a very little background with geometric and binomial series, and you can learn it in very little time (I think).

Comment: @Masacroso will do! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets mark the result of each dice roll with $x_i$

$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{10}\geq 18$$
And
$$1\leq x_i\leq6$$

Which is the same as
$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{10}\geq 8$$
And
$$0\leq x_i\leq 5$$

## The complement

Lets have a look at the complement:
$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{10}< 8$$
Where $0\leq x_i\leq 5$

### There are 2 case:

### Case 1: $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{10}\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

No need to account for the bounds on $x_i$

The number of solution to the equation is
$$c_1=\sum_{k=0}^{5}{9+k\choose k}$$

### Case 2: $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{10}\in \{6,7\}$

Same as the above, but we need to subtract the illegal solutions of $x_i\geq 6$

There is one illegal solutions for $k=6$, which is $x_i=6$
And two illegal solutions for $k=7$, which are $x_i=6$ or $x_i=7$

$$c_2={9+6\choose 6}-10{8+0\choose 0} + {9+7\choose 7}-10{8+1\choose 1}-10{8+0\choose 0}$$

### Summary

The complementary probability is
$$q=\frac{c_1+c_2}{6^{10}}$$
Thus the probability of rolling a sum of at least 18 with 10 6-sided dice is
$$p=1-q=1-\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{7}{9+k\choose k}-110}{6^{10}}$$

Comment: This answer yields a probability of more than $1$!!!!!

Comment: Now that is much closer to what I got on a Python script ($19338$ samples of the complementary event; your answer yields $19368$ for some reason).

Comment: Unfortunately, the script is fairly simple, I don't think that I could have written it wrong.

Comment: Is that $100$ outside the $\sum$ or inside the $\sum$?

Comment: @barakmanos, try again, the probability is $0.9996800194541822$

Comment: I'm not calculating the probability, only the numerator of your fraction. Assuming that the "$100$" is outside the $\sum$, your result differs than mine by only $10$ additional samples. Could it possibly be "$110$"?

Comment: @barakmanos, you are right  $10{8+0\choose 0} +10{8+1\choose 1}+10{8+0\choose 0}=110$

Answer (score 3):

You want to calculate $1-P(\mbox{sum}\le 17)$. Now, $P(\mbox{sum}\le 17)=\sum_{k=10}^{17}P(\sum=k)$ (formally, it would be $P(\mbox{sum}\le 17)=\sum_{k=1}^{17}P(\sum=k)$, but the minimum sum is 10. Then for $k\le 10$, $P(\mbox{sum}=k)=0$).

Now, fix $k\in\{10,11,...,17\}$. You want to distribute $k$ identical balls into 10 distinguishable boxes such that each box has at least one ball and at most 6 balls. By generating functions method, it can be done with polynomial $p(x)=(x+x^2+...+x^6)^{10}=x^{10}(1+x+...+x^5)^{10}=x^{10}(1-x^6)^{10}(1-x)^{-10}$.

Now, the coefficient of $x^k$ in $p(x)$ is the same of $x^{k-10}$ on $(1-x^6)^{10}(1-x)^{-10}\\=\left(\binom{10}{0}-\binom{10}{1}x^6+\binom{10}{2}x^{12}-...+\binom{10}{10}x^{60}\right)\sum_{r=0}^\infty\binom{10+r-1}{r}x^r$.

But $k-10=0,1,2,...,7$. Thus, coefficients are

$x^0$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{9}{0}$

$x^1$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{10}{1}$

$x^2$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{11}{2}$

$x^3$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{12}{3}$

$x^4$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{13}{4}$

$x^5$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{14}{5}$

$x^6$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{15}{6}-\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{0}$

$x^7$) Is $\binom{10}{0}\binom{16}{7}-\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{1}$

Thus, the total of sums of the dices for $\sum\le 17$ is $\binom{9}{0}+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{11}{2}+\binom{12}{3}+\binom{13}{4}+\binom{14}{5}+\binom{15}{6}+\binom{16}{7}-10\binom{10}{0}-10\binom{9}{1}=\binom{17}{7}-110$.

But the total of outputs that the 10 dices can be are $6*6*...*6=6^{10}$.

Thus, answer is $1-\frac{\binom{17}{7}-110}{6^{10}}=1-\frac{19338}{6^{10}}=0.99968$

Comment: $2^9+90=602$ sounds like much less than the actual number of samples that belong in the complementary event. I got $19338$ when running a script.

Comment: That only added $180$ to the previous result.

Comment: The combination of $[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4]$ alone yields $720$ possible permutations.

Comment: You're welcome, just fix that "$6^10$" down there :)

Comment: Oh, and hmmmm... one die, many dice.